# How can I configure the Django DATABASES settings at runtime?

Tags: database, django, settings

These days I am studying how to program on BAE. BAE is a cloud platform like GAE. It supports python 2.7 and MySQL. But there is a problem, BAE provides the `DATABASE` information in the request. I can get these settings like this:

```
port = request.META['HTTP_BAE_ENV_ADDR_SQL_PORT']
```

but how can I configure the `DATABASES` setting at runtime?

I tried to write a middleware for this problem, like this:

```
from  django.conf import settings

class bae_database(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        BAE_DB = {
            'default': {
                'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
                'NAME': 'django',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
                'USER': 'root',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
                'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
                'HOST': 'localhost',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
                'PORT': '3306',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
            },
        } 
        settings.DATABASES = BAE_DB
```

Then in `settings.py` file I add this middleware to `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` and set `DATABASES = {}`.
As a result I get this error message:

```
You haven't set the database ENGINE setting yet.
```

In fact the middleware works, because in Settings part of the Django error page I get:

```
DATABASES   
{'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 'HOST': 'localhost', 'NAME': 'django', 'PASSWORD': '********************', 'PORT': '3306', 'USER': 'root'}}
```

I don't know why, I changed the `DATABASES` attribute, but it is useless. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Is `DATABASES == {}` in `settings.py`? - If so try setting it in `settings.py` to something - e.g. the test value you currently show in in your middware.

Comment: django will connect database since runserver only if I set DATABASE={}. the test value is work-well config for my computer.if I set DATABASES to test value, it has no problem .but on BAE I can just get the config from request.

Comment: so it's meaningless to set static setting

Comment: yes but what i am saying is that in `settings.py` you should set `DATABASE` to a non-empty, valid value. You can change it in the middleware but you need to have *something* in `DATABASES` when you start up other Django will refuse to run.

Comment: Thanks for your advice,but it still doesn't work.I set database engine to 'sqlite3',create a empty db fileand start up django, in the error page, Exception Location:  /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute, line 200,  in the setting part DATABASES  
{'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 'HOST': 'localhost', 'NAME': 'django', 'PASSWORD': '********************', 'PORT': '3306', 'USER': 'root'}}

Comment: i would set the `ENGINE` to the same as whatever BAE uses - i'm not familiar with Django's db code but I would expect that dynamically changing db engine would be much more likely to fail than changing port or host. Best approach is to query BAE for a set of DB settings and use that as your initial `DATABASES` setup. That way your middleware will have to change the minimal number of settings.

Comment: During testing you method this afternoon, I find that I can't access DATABASES settings in my middleware, if I code like settings.DATABASE['default'], it will throw KeyError . now  i will use your method ,set the BAE database settings to django settings, i believe it will work very well. thanks again.